# Golang HTTP server requests async or sync?

Tags: http, go, concurrency

I have a RESTful API in Golang that my Angular website calls.

Does the Go http module by default handle requests in sequence or concurrently?

Also, if my HandlerFunc in Go calls a python script, would concurrent calls to this HandlerFunc spawn multiple python processes, or would they be blocked till one is complete?

Comment: Concurrent. Possible duplicate of [Webhook process run on another goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782073/webhook-process-run-on-another-goroutine/37783535#37783535); and [Server instances with multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070323/server-instances-with-multiple-users/44070394#44070394); and [Process Management for the Go Webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529511/process-management-for-the-go-webserver/37531953#37531953).

Comment: Gotcha! And how about calling the python script? Will the concurrent goroutines be blocked?

Comment: I don't know how you call them and what they do, but in general you could say that the calling goroutine (request) will be blocked, but you can call the script from multiple requests, concurrently.

Comment: `exec.Command("python", pythonFile, args)` is how I call it

Comment: I would suggest you test it by adding code in python that sleeps for several seconds.

Comment: @WiredPrairie That's just the way you create an `exec.Cmd`. `Cmd.Run()` runs it and waits for it to complete (blocks). `Cmd.Start()` starts it but does not wait (does not block). If you use `Cmd.Start()`, you may use `Cmd.Wait()` to wait for it to complete.

Comment: @icza -- I understand that -- I'm suggesting that a little bit of testing could resolve these questions easily.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Actually I meant to address that comment to the asker NishantRoy...

Comment: @icza - :) gotcha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by default all http requests can be executed concurrently.

If you are executing a python script, then indeed a separate process will be spawned and they will execute concurrently.

Please note that this carries the potential risk of spawning too many processes and running out of resources.